# Maintaining border size

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS class:

```
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 30%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */

    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I want to keep the same border width even when the number changes, from 10 to 9.
Right now, the border expands when the number changes.

Here's a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bx2o1nwk/) of what I mean.

I've already tried changing the padding attribute but I can't make it work.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The border size is in both case 2px. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant width. I want the same 'box' for every number, even if it has two digits instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Add `display:inline-block` and then `line-height` to vertically align the numbers. By setting this the box will expand. adjust the `height` & `width` as per your need. If so, do not forget to adjust the `line-height` relative to height of the box.

```css
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 30%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
    line-height:36px; /*vertcally center the numbers*/
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    display:inline-block; /* Added */
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<span class='numberCircle'>10</span>
<span class='numberCircle'>9</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just explicitly set the width.  I suggest a unit of mesure that's relative to the font size (namely `em`s)

Edit: it seems all you were missing was `display:inline-block`.  You can't set the width of an inline element.  Adding it will probably get you most of the way there.

```css
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 30%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */

    /*width: 36px;
    height: 36px;*/
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight:bold;
  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;

}
```

```html
<span class='numberCircle'>10</span>
<span class='numberCircle'>9</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out these properties:

```
line-height:20px; /*this will center your numbers inside the border*/
width: 20px; /*set the same as line-height and height in order to give a square shaped border*/
height: 20px; /*set the same as line-height and width in order to give a square shaped border*/
display: inline-block;
```

line-height, width and height will shape your box. While the new display property will help to align the elements in a "one after the other" fashion. :)